# Pasar variable php a cuadro modal uso html y css

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli, modal

como puedo hacer para pasar variables php a mi cuadro modal.

Tengo mi cuadro modal hecho con css y mi consulta en php esta con while esto me imprime una serie de datos consecutivos, entonces tambien tengo dentro de ese while un boton que dice info. la idea es poder presionar el boton info y que por lo menos me lleve el id del registro al cuadro modal:

Esta es mi consulta:

```
<table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">POSICIÓN</th>
                                    <th scope="col">TRABAJO A REALIZAR</th>
                                    <th scope="col">HORA SALIDA</th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
<?php
            $iniciado=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `p_atendidas` where refe='$elid'");
            while($posreal = mysqli_fetch_array($iniciado)){
?>                          
                                <tr>
    <th scope="row">
    <select class="camptwo" required>
    <option><?php echo $posreal['posatendi']?></option>
    </select></th>

    <td style="font-size:12px;">
    <select class="camptwo" required>
    <option><?php echo $posreal['tipotrabajo']?></option>
    </select></td>
                                    <td><input type='time' class='camptwo' style='width:140px;' name='horafinal[]' required ></td>
                                    <td><a href="#openModal?id_patendi=<?php echo $posreal['id_patendi']?>" class="md-close">info</a></td>


                                </tr>                           
<?php
            }       
?>                              
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Y este es mi cuadro modal con HTML y CSS

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

<?php $id_patendi=$_GET['id_patendi']; ?>


<input type='text' name='id_patendi' value="<?php echo $id_patendi?>">

    </div>
</div>
```

Actualmente mi cuadro modal funciona si le presiono click al boton info que se encuentra dentro del while, pero para pasar la variable de la menra que lo hago no funciona. que podria hacer en ese caso? todo esta en la misma pantalla.

No se si se pueda hacer con javascript.

Saludos y muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan aportar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establece un atributo custom a tu anchor, al mostrar tu modal cargas el dato por javascript y lo asignas al value del input.

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">
    <select class="camptwo" required>
      <option><?php echo $posreal['posatendi']?></option>
    </select></th>

  <td style="font-size:12px;">
    <select class="camptwo" required>
      <option><?php echo $posreal['tipotrabajo']?></option>
    </select></td>
  <td><input type='time' class='camptwo' style='width:140px;' name='horafinal[]' required></td>
  <td><a href="#openModal" id_patendi="<?php echo $posreal['id_patendi']?>" class="md-close">info</a></td>
</tr>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>


    <input id="inputModal" type='text' name='id_patendi' value="">

  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>

<script>
  let id_patendi = document.querySelector('.md-close').getAttribute('id_patendi')
  let inputModal = document.querySelector('#inputModal')
  inputModal.setAttribute('value', id_patendi)

</script>
```

Comment: Estupendo, ya me sirvio perfecto muchas gracias amigo. saludos.